# Recover the prime from the prime power

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, primes

**Definition**: a *prime power* is a natural number that can be expressed in the form p<sup>n</sup> where p is a prime and n is a natural number.

**Task**: Given a prime power p<sup>n</sup> > 1, return the prime p.

**Testcases**:

```
input output
9     3
16    2
343   7
2687  2687
59049 3
```

**Scoring**: This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Can ```n``` be 1?

Comment: @user202729: In the 4th test-case `n = 1`.

Comment: Maybe it would have been more challenging to get the *power* part instead of the prime part. As it is, this is just "Get the lowest factor that isn't 1"

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvk/7X@l0uH9Crp2Cof3K@n8t@QyNOMyNjHmMjKzMOcytTQwsQQA)

Comment: Are you sure that a list (or `[]` around the number) is a valid output?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: [Relevant meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/47066)

Comment: Huh, didn't know about that, thanks.

Comment: For those wondering, [`f = push list of prime factors (no duplicates)`](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/6d2c4d5/docs/info.txt#L104)

Answer (score 13):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>209</s> 207 bytes

```
T.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:Listen tothy!Page:You cat!Scene V:.Page:You be the sum ofyou a cat!Be the product ofthe quotient betweenI you you worse I?If soLet usScene V.Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEER/ZXuX4EEPzUUqeCgUFBRBxENst7ai2ZpsqP36mrXiYWHnMcOM7x7jeFDZ3bxnamduOFNZyZBrtS/RojznjWV0IBYwtgJxXUTpovWMFpi4GRLB@kQBSsPJFD5q9adXBG4QfHgC1UME5mtcT7hzVIXYS7WoVyBu0XIMcY9oc5CAXE/Ox1GrvAZPBTIE/6tS2y5OadA4HsdlOl@kHw)

`(I/you)*you<I` is shorter than `I%you>0` in SPL.

Comment: The right tool for the job.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, <s>46</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```java
n->{int r=1;for(;n%++r>0;);return r;}
```

-7 bytes indirectly thanks to *@Tsathoggua*.
-2 bytes thanks to *JoKing*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hU7NCsIwDL77FLkILeLY/B9F30AvHsVDrZ1kbtnouoFIn71206sMkkC@n3zJZSfn@f3pVSGbBo4S6T0BQLLaZFJpOPXrAIBi/SQuAuJCh2qstKjgBAR78DQ/vHsJ7hORVYYJms5meIgFF0bb1hCgcF58rXV7K4L1d6Gr8A5lSGdna5AelytI/o0@vxqry6hqbVQHyhbEKFIs5cMjf/lkMyJYrpYjisVmtx2RrNN49fvETZz/AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{               // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int r=1;         //  Start the result-integer `r` at 1
  for(;n%++r>0;);  //  Increase `r` by 1 before every iteration with `++r`
                   //  and loop until `n` is divisible by `r`
  return r;}       //  After the loop, return `r` as result
```

Comment: Following [Luis Mendo's answer in python3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167121), would it be possible to write `n->{for(int i=1;++i<=n;)if(n%i<1)return i;}` to get 43 characters? (I don't speak Java.)

Comment: @Tsathoggua As you have it right now not, since Java methods must always have a return. `n->{for(int i=1;++i<=n;)if(n%i<1)return i;return n;}` would work, but is unfortunately longer. Java can have a single return in infinite loops however, which does indeed save bytes, so thanks! `n->{for(int i=1;;)if(n%++i<1)return i;}`. Since `i` will become `n` eventually (like with the test case `2687`) and `n%n==0`, the `i<=n` isn't required in this case.

Comment: How about [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##hU7NCsIwDL77FLkILeLY/B9F30AvHsVDrZ1kbtnouoFIn71206sMkkC@n3zJZSfn@f3pVSGbBo4S6T0BQLLaZFJpOPXrAIBi/SQuAuJCh2qstKjgBAR78DQ/vHsJ7hORVYYJms5meIgFF0bb1hCgcF58rXV7K4L1d6Gr8A5lSGdna5AelytI/o0@vxqry6hqbVQHyhbEKFIs5cMjf/lkMyJYrpYjisVmtx2RrNN49fvETZz/AA). I'm not familiar enough with Java to see if any more can be golfed

Comment: @JoKing I don't see anything to golf further, so thanks for the -2.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to mathmandan*

```python
f=lambda n,x=2:n%x and f(n,x+1)or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYdBCoMwFAX3nuJtCgkNxajVKniS0kVaDQ3ojyS/EE@fZmAG5jj566nNbj98YMQzVsVbXDmsn1@IztPmdsdC1wWZ7byZ/b0YkEpzM9ElwdACK8pftfQBKdtShiM8RwXdK7Rdq9D0j0HhPnb1@Joq4AiOWFjBUuY/)

Recursive function that finds the first factor larger than 1

Comment: Nice. You can (usually) save a byte if you replace `if/else` with `and/or`. Like, `f=lambda n,x=2:n%x and f(n,x+1)or x`.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
Yfu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzKt9P9/U0sDE0sA)

#### Explanation:

```
       % Implicit input:      [59049]
Yf     % Prime factorization: [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
  u    % Unique elements:     [3]
       % Implicit output
```

Comment: Very nice improvement! I would upvote again :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 16 bytes

```matlab
@(x)factor(x)(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzLTG5JL8IyNAw1PyfpmFsYqz5HwA)

#### Explanation:

```matlab
@(x)              % Anonymous function taking x as input
    factor(x)     % Prime factorization
             (1)  % Get the first element
```

Or:

```matlab
@(x)max(factor(x))  % the makeup of makeup artists
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>80</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```
[S S T  T   N
_Push_-1][S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_number][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S N
_Push_0][T  T   T   _Retrieve][S N
T   _Swap][T    S T T   _Modulo][N
T   T   N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][S S T T   N
_Push_-1][T S S N
_Multiply][T    N
S T _Print_as_number]
```

-20 bytes thanks to *@JoKing*.

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0GBk5NLQUGBi5MLzACxgUwgAWYCxTk5QQRIGVgBJ1gWqFyB8/9/YxNjAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = STDIN as integer
Integer i = -1
Start LOOP:
  i = i - 1
  if(n modulo-i is negative)
    Go to next iteration of LOOP
  else
    i = i * -1
    Print i
    Exit with error: No exit defined
```

**Example run: [`input = 9`](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0GBk5NLQUGBi5MLzACxgUwgAWYCxTk5QQRIGVgBJ1gWqFyB8/9/SwA)**

```
Command   Explanation                    Stack        Heap     STDIN    STDOUT    STDERR

SSTTN     Push -1                        [-1]
SSSN      Push 0                         [-1,0]
TNTT      Read STDIN as integer          [-1]         {0:9}    9
NSSN      Create Label_LOOP              [-1]         {0:9}
 SSSTN    Push 1                         [-1,1]       {0:9}
 TSST     Subtract top two (-1-1)        [-2]         {0:9}
 SNS      Duplicate top (-2)             [-2,-2]      {0:9}
 SSSN     Push 0                         [-2,-2,0]    {0:9}
 TTT      Retrieve                       [-2,-2,9]    {0:9}
 SNT      Swap top two                   [-2,9,-2]    {0:9}
 TSTT     Modulo top two (9%-2)          [-2,-1]      {0:9}
 NTSN     If neg.: Jump to Label_LOOP    [-2]         {0:9}
 
 SSTTN    Push -1                        [-2,-1]      {0:9}
 TSST     Subtract top two (-2-1)        [-3]         {0:9}
 SNS      Duplicate top (-2)             [-3,-3]      {0:9}
 SSSN     Push 0                         [-3,-3,0]    {0:9}
 TTT      Retrieve                       [-3,-3,9]    {0:9}
 SNT      Swap top two                   [-3,9,-3]    {0:9}
 TSTT     Modulo top two (9%-3)          [-3,0]       {0:9}
 NTSN     If neg.: Jump to Label_LOOP    [-3]         {0:9}
 SSTTN    Push -1                        [-3,-1]      {0:9}
 TSSN     Multiply top two (-3*-1)       [3]          {0:9}
 TNST     Print as integer               []           {0:9}             3
                                                                                  error
```

Program stops with an error: No exit found.

Comment: Do you need the `i == n` check? `n%n` would be 0 anyway

Comment: @JoKing Ah, of course. Thanks, 19 bytes saved right there. :)

Comment: Could you only loop if not `n%i` and call the print afterwards?

Comment: @JoKing I'm pretty sure not. Whitespace doesn't really have loops, it just has jumps to labels. The only three options I have is to: 1. jump to a certain label unconditionally; 2. jump to a certain label if the top of the stack is 0; 3. jump to a certain label if the top of the stack is negative. Unfortunately there isn't a "jump to label if positive" to continue the loop. I could accomplish this by multiplying by -1 before checking for negative, but I doubt that will be shorter.

Comment: Tried to do it with a negative modulus and ended up at <s>62</s>[60 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0GBk5NLQUGBi5MLzOACC3AqKICZIHFOThABFuWEywKVK3D@/29sYgwA) (yay). Turns out you can't store at negative heap addresses (though 0 saved a couple of bytes)

Comment: @JoKing Thanks again! Yes, I tried saving an input in a negative heap address before, but unfortunately that doesn't work. Also, TIO works as intended with negative modulo, but apparently [vii5ard](http://vii5ard.github.io/whitespace/) which I usually use to develop in (easier to debug and see all commands) will give `9%-2 = 1` instead of `-1`. But I use TIO as lead in my Whitespace answers, which works completely fine. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 25 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=2)=>n%k?f(n,k+1):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfb1kjT1i5PNds@DcTTNtS0yv6fnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RpmGpAASamgr6@grGXKhShmZwKSM0KWMTY5iUOZqUkZmFOUwXkIkma2ppYGIJte4/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 30 bytes

```
n=>fori=2n>i i++if1>n%i breaki
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P8/WLi2/KNPWKM8uUyFTWzszzdAuTzVTIakoNTE7839BUWZeiUaahrGJsabmfwA)

Comment: `0==` can be `1>` I think.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 2 bytes

```
hP
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hP&input=343&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ÆfḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rDHYv@//9vamlgYgkA)

`ÆfṪ`, `ÆfX` could also be seriously competing functions.
`ÆfQ` could be a seriously competing full program.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 28 bytes

```c
f(k,p){for(p=1;k%++p;);k=p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1unQLM6Lb9Io8DW0DpbVVu7wFrTOtu2wLr2f25iZp6GZnVBUWZeSZqGkmqKgq2tgrGOAoRhBGOYw0XMLOBsYyUdhTQNS00QaWgGpoxNjME0SBmYYWppYGKpqQm0CQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 34 bytes

```forth
: f 1 begin 1+ 2dup mod 0= until ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtHCoAwFAX3nmJwKwZjL@hhLFHBEoKeP343M/CKud2zxav55X2LQTMu636hI9L5tZz3TNLzXs9@0MnE8scFyqFCiAdCuSkmRxc02ECXgizPhGlZV6KiSXJp/Ac)

#### Explanation

1. Iterate integers starting from 2
2. Stop and return when you find one that divides n with no remainder

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f               \ Define a new word
  1               \ place a 1 on the stack (to use as a counter/index)
  begin           \ start indefinite loop
    1+ 2dup       \ increment counter and duplicate counter and prime power
    mod           \ calculate power % index
  0= until        \ end the loop if modulus is 0 (no remainder)
;                 \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> 26 bytes

@Giuseppe with different logic and a shorter solution:

```r
(x=2:(n=scan()))[!n%%x][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PC1shKI8@2ODkxT0NTUzNaMU9VtSI22jD2v6mlgYnlfwA)

Original:

```r
numbers::primeFactors(scan())[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P680Nym1qNjKqqAoMzfVLTG5JL@oWKM4OTFPQ1Mz2jD2v6mlgYnlfwA)

This is obviously a much superior port of the [05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167107/79980) solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>7</s> 2 bytes

```apl
⊃⍭
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24RHXc2PetcC2QqWXGkKhmZAwtjEGEgamVmYAylTSwMTSwA)

`⍭` gives a list of factors, `⊃` gets the first of them.

Answer (score 2):

## Vyxal 1, 1 byte

```
′
```

There was a builtin just for this.

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%8Fh&inputs=6&header=&footer=)

Comment: @Lyxal Is that because of Vyxal 2? If so, I can label mine Vyxal 1 and you can post a separate answer.

Comment: no, it's the exact same program. turns out you don't need the `h` at the end.

Comment: it just looks different

Comment: @Lyxal I don't understand. Just the first command also gives the exponents instead of just the primes, right?

Comment: The `′` gives _all_ prime factors. The question only wants one (hence why I made it `′h`). However, other answers seem to get away with printing all factors, so it's just `′` (or `Ǐ`)

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 10 bytes

```
(xx+?)\1*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc@9UsJAFIbhnquIGYecQyQQQBTWhcqChkJLpdiBQ7K62ezsLhD5ab0AL9EbiVAwY/0U3/d@iK1wSyuNbzsjV2SLUn/SV225pl3wQtlzZQD2fNJp1VBV8RTf09Zt3ersMfHlq7dSZ4CJU3JJMLxrDxCZ4122y6UiAMUtiZWSmgDxhuuNUnjIuEqcUdJD1I6QyTWA5lmiSGc@x0nveJRuLuYguRHW0Ux7yN66C8Qr0H/Qk3Saji@MPrflLpzprVByFVihMxoHYazYurTA5BMnJuMYz4MFD6swsWRIeJCYFMIvc7CIB9dsmnOUh0tHyszGO29BxlHw@/0TRHHxli6uV9npVI8a6bDRH/QbveHjQ@N@1B2M/gA)

Works by finding the smallest prime factor. Takes its input in bijective unary, as a sequence of `x` characters in which the length represents the number. The output is returned in capture group 1.

```
         # No anchor needed, since every input N>=2 returns an output
(xx+?)   # \1 = the smallest number >=2 for which:
\1*$     # N-\1 is divisible by \1
```

Comment: Wow. The things regex can do...

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
ḋh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7oz//41NjP9HAQA)

#### Explanation

```
ḋ       Prime decomposition
 h      Head
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

```
0{q:
```

Select `{` the first `0` of the prime factors `q:`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N@gutDqvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagiWMYWgGYxmbGMOYRmYW5jC2qaWBieV/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 1 byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCVP@/ze1NDCxBAA)

Comment: [U+1D414](https://www.charbase.com/1d414-unicode-mathematical-bold-capital-u) is one character, but in UTF-8 and UTF-16 this is represented by 4 bytes.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Correct, but this isn't in UTF-8 nor UTF-16.

Comment: @RuudHelderman You may want to see [Neim codepage](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page).

Comment: @JungHwanMin Thanks; browsing Okx's earlier Neim submissions, I noticed my slightly ignorant reaction wasn't the first. Clever feature, but far from obvious; warrants explanation (as done [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141806/a-complementary-quine#141818)). Quoting [code-golf tag info](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info): "Unless the question is specified to be scored by characters, it is scored by bytes. If it doesn't specify a character encoding to use for scoring, answers which use Unicode code points outside 0 to 255 should state the encoding used."

Comment: @RuudHelderman per [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5879/60043), if an answer does not specify an encoding, it defaults to the language's default encoding. If that doesn't exist, then it is UTF-8. In this case, Neim has a defined default encoding, so it is assumed to be the encoding of the answer, without the answerer having to explain as such.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
f n=until((<1).mod n)(+1)2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7Y0ryQzR0PDxlBTLzc/RSFPU0PbUNPof25iZp5tQVFmXomCikJuYoFCmkK0iY6FjqGZjpG5jqmOsYlx7H8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
Divisors[#][[2]]&
```

The second smallest divisor.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
←p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@jtgkF////j7bUMTTTMTYx1jEyszDXMbU0MLGMBQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 19 bytes

```lua
index(factors(a),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z8zLyW1QiMtMbkkv6hYI1FTx1Dz////xibGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-g`, 1 byte

```
k
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=aw==&input=MTYKLWc=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

*Inspired by [Kevin Cruijssen's answer in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167115/36398)*.

*<s>2</s> 3 bytes removed thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*.

```python
lambda n:[i+1for i in range(n)if n%-~i<1][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxDsIgFAXQvV9xlyYQaVIEqTT6JciAUfQl9bUhLC7@OqZnPdu3vlc2LV9vbUmf@yOB50AHndcCAjFK4tdTsKQM7ocfXXQMOrb96/7BK2inYKxROLrzpHDydvRx7oCtEFeRRZWy/QE)

Comment: You have an extra space before the `if`, and the condition can be `<1`

Comment: You can [save one byte](https://tio.run/##FcmxDsIgFAXQvV9xlyYQaVIEqTT6JciAUfQl9bUhLC7@OqZnPdu3vlc2LV9vbUmf@yOB50AHndcCAjFK4tdTsKQM7ocfXXQMOrb96/7BK2inYKxROLrzpHDydvRx7oCtEFeRRZWy/QE) by doing `range(n)` and incrementing `i` in place

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 31 bytes

```powershell
param($a)(2..$a|?{!($a%$_)})[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRU8NIT08lsca@WhHIU1WJ16zVjDaI/f//v5GZhTkA)

Constructs a range from `2` to input `$a`, pulls out those elements `where` (`?`) the modulo operation `%` results in a zero `!(...)` (i.e., those that are divisors of `$a`), and then takes the smallest `[0]` one thereof. That's left on the pipeline, output is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

## Visual Basic .NET (.NET Framework v4.5), <s>123</s> 71 bytes

*-52 bytes thanks to @Jo King*

```vb
Function A(n)
For i=n To 2 Step-1
A=If(n Mod i=0,i,A)
Next
End Function
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZC5CsJAEIb7fYopdyGRHF4pUgQPEIyNgnWOUUbirGR3xbeP8epMN8zH/8/H3Mm4ovHLwlDlM1r/XlZdrmvXIORiSVcgDy5QGNiwxTO23dpxZUkzZJKVWOsWKGU4aIhgb/HmhyJLNyfJ0Lf0KPDIy5TY4cOKFdfwi3d7V0JeEEslxEKz0Q2Oji1Z3BKjzGSi1N99OB0A8TgeINF0PhtAkyQYvy693Xqlz/B9QPcE)

Ungolfed:

```vb
Function A(input As Long) As Long
    For i = input To 2 Step -1
        A = If (input Mod i = 0, i, A)
    Next
End Function
```

Explanation:

The `i` loop searches backwards from the first number, and finds all numbers that divide it evenly. Because we are going backwards, the smallest is stored in the vairable `A`.

VB gives you a free variable that matches your function name (in my case, `A`). At the end of the function execution, the value in that variable is returned (barring an explicit `Return` statement.

Comment: You don't need the prime check at all. The smallest factor of a number (other than 1) is guaranteed to be a prime, otherwise there would be a smaller factor

Comment: @JoKing D'oh! Of course, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
{grep($_%%*,2..$_)[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Or0otUBDJV5VVUvHSE9PJV4z2iC29n@ahqWmXnFipTVXmoahGZxpbGIMZxuZWZjDOaaWBiZQHf8B)

Anonymous code block that filters the factors of the range of 2 to the input and returns the first one. I tried using `^$` to save 2 bytes, but that didn't work in the case that the input was prime.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
f y=[x|x<-[2..],mod y x<1]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h0ja6oqbCRjfaSE8vVic3P0WhUqHCxjBWUdHgf25iZp5tQVFmXolKmoKR@X8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 17 bytes

```
n->factor(n)[1,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLCoAgFEbhrfw4SrhCpj0c1EbCgQSGEHaRJq3ebHY@OBxKUifXiBU1qy2G47lLl@WuSfsamK@3y1AbuKT8tBQ/BGJ7JGF3BD0RjDWEYVpmwuh667ysHw)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 17 bytes

```
n->divisors(n)[2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y4lsyyzOL@oWCNPM9oo9n9iQUFOpUaegq6dQkFRZl4JkKkE4igppAFVaOooRFvqKBia6SgYmxjrKBiZWZjrKJhaGphYxmr@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 100 bytes

```ruby
require"prime"
i=gets.to_i
Prime.each(i){|p|(1..i).each{|n|c=p**n==i
    puts p if c
    exit if c}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyi1sDSzKFWpoCgzN1WJK9M2PbWkWK8kPz6TKwAkpJeamJyhkalZXVNQo2Gop5epCRaprsmrSbYt0NLKs7XN5FIAgoLSkmKFAoXMNIVkMD@1IrMEzKut/f/f1NLAxBIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
|fh
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Cfh&i=9%0A16%0A343%0A2687%0A59049&a=1&m=2)

First element of prime factorization.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

```julia
n->[2:n;][n.%(2:n).<1][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P1y7ayCrPOjY6T09VA8jS1LMxjI02jP2fm1igkVeaq2tXUJSZV5KTp5EG4mpq6ihEG8cZ6yiYx5nqKBgaxhnpKBjFWcRq/gcA)

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P106jyNbIKk8zOk9PtUjPxjA2OvZ/bmKBRl5prq5dQVFmXklOnkYaiKupqaMQbRxnrKNgHmeqo2BoGGeko2AUZxGr@R8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->n,i=1{(1>n%i+=1)?i:redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrRCoJAEEDRXxmUoGiK1jXNYKYPiR7K1lqETUylWOfbt@3lPhxuP96@oaGwYYeWlF8qdgu7JrU62WNv7i8JviLWCKogzhB0rolLhKw4lBFiEfbVLv9PsjXX@gl@bhGmGbpxeEOS@laAGFLfnNuLIJhPZ@rBukekSRIJPw)

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic, 39 bytes

```
INPUT x
p=2
WHILE x\p<x/p
p=p+1
WEND
?p
```

Trial division; finds the first factor greater than 1, which is guaranteed to be the prime factor.

The only trick here is the condition `x\p<x/p`, which uses integer vs. floating point division to test whether "`x` is not divisible by `p`." See [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156592/16766) for details.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5MSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTklMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMyUyQyUwQTE2JTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMDIlMkMlMEEzNDMlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwNyUyQyUwQTI2ODclMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMjY4NyUyQyUwQTU5MDQ5JTIwLSUzRSUyMDMlMkMmZmxhZ3M9Qw==)

Unique prime factors built-in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 32 bytes

*-17 bytes thanks to [@Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)!*

```
d=[2...n]
f(n)=d[mod(n,d)=0].min
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cqu5u64eqh)

Find the smallest factor (>1) of \$n\$.

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 49 bytes

```
p=[\sqrt[i]n\for i=[n...1]]
f(n)=p[\ceil(p)=p][1]
```

**Explaination**

Finds the smallest integer value of \$\sqrt[i]n\$ (\$i\in\mathbb Z\$)

In other words, make \$\sqrt[i]n\$ an integer with the greatest value of \$i\$

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6lp4tehbat)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qygcwuqbv6)

Comment: @AidenChow darn, i'm surprised i didn't think of that

Comment: It's always helpful to check other peoples' answers :P

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 17 bytes

```lua
primefactors(n)/z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/7@gKDM3NS0xuSS/qFgjT1O/6v///6aWBiaWAA)