# Prime Power Switch

Tags: code-golf, primes

**Input:**
A positive integer `n=p^q` where `p` and `q` are [prime](https://www.mathopenref.com/prime-number.html).

**Output:**
Output the result of `q^p`

**Test cases (in, out):**

```
4, 4
8, 9
25, 32
27, 27
49, 128
121, 2048
125, 243
343, 2187
1331, 177147
3125, 3125, 
16807, 78125, 
823543, 823543
161051, 48828125
19487171, 1977326743
```

**Scoring:**
This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code in bytes win! Input and output maybe in any reasonable format suitable to your language.

Related:
[Recover the power from the prime power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167199/recover-the-power-from-the-prime-power)
[Recover the prime from the prime power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167106/recover-the-prime-from-the-prime-power)

Comment: That `q` is a prime does not seem to matter.

Comment: Fun fact: of course if p = q, then p^q = q^p. But if p != q, then the only pair of integers satisfying p^q = q^p is (2, 4), with 2^4 = 4^2 = 16.

Comment: @Stef Can you link a proof of that? Can't seem to find the right google keywords

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms From \$p^q = q^p\$, taking the natural log of both sides gives \$q \ln p = p \ln q\$, or \$q / \ln q = p / \ln p\$. So, we want two distinct positive integers that map to the same value under \$f(x) = x / \ln x\$. Looking at the [graph of this function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%2F+ln+%28x%29+from+1+to+5) for \$x>1\$, we see it has a single minimum between 2 and 3 (actually \$e\$ as some calculus confirms). So, \$p\$ and \$q\$ must be on opposite sides of this minimum. Since they're integers and above 1, the lower one must be 2, and its matching value is 4.

Comment: @xnor Ah, thanks! A really simple answer to something I'd never really thought about before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ÓOsfm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8GT/4rTc//@NTAE)

**Commented:**

```
        # implicit input            25
Ó       # prime factor exponents    [0, 0, 2]
 O      # sum                       2
  s     # swap (with input)         25, 2
   f    # unique prime factors      [5], 2
    m   # power                     [32]
```

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
n=input()
p=2
while n%p:p+=1
P=p**n-1
print(n**n/P%P)**p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtbCoMwEEX/ZxVBEDSl1MmjiUJ@ugK3UCTUQI1DHWm7eqv04144HA59eZyz2t5jekaBXfzEoSiKLYeUaeWqBgoK/jaX1NEpIPSBpMxnBHqlzFXe4dKXfS0lbUdswIOyoByYFlDhPgvaaECtEfRBePWN2x8bi1Dd0kNwXFgM9yUugtMUxbxyDV5pe3St8Q4d/gA)

We first find the prime \$p\$ for which \$n=p^q\$ by incrementing \$p\$ until we get a divisor on \$n\$. After that, we find the exponent \$q\$  with a mathematical trick first discovered by Sp3000 and used in [Perfect power logarithms](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?Perfect%20power%20logarithms) on Anarchy Golf.

We note that
$$ \frac{n-1}{p-1} =  \frac{p^q-1}{p-1} = 1 + p + p^2 \dots+p^{q-2}+p^{q-1}$$
Working modulo \$p-1\$, we have \$p \equiv 1\$, so each of \$q\$ the summands on the right hand side equals 1, and so:
$$ \frac{n-1}{p-1} \equiv q \space \bmod (p-1)$$

We'd now like to extract \$q\$. We'd like to get there by applying the modulus operator `%(p-1)` to the left hand side. But this requires that \$q<p-1\$, which is not guaranteed, or we'll get a different value of `q%(p-1)`.

Fortunately, we can get around this with one more trick. We can replace \$n\$ with \$n^c\$ and \$p\$ with \$p^c\$ for some positive number \$c\$, and still have \$n^c=(p^c)^q\$. Since the exponent \$q\$ relating them is unchanged, we can extract it as above, but make it so that \$q<p^c-1\$. For this, \$c=n\$ more than suffices and is short for golfing, though it makes larger test cases time out.

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Linux utils, 17

```bash
factor|dc -e?zr^p
```

- `factor` takes a number as input and factorizes it.  The output is the input number, followed by a colon, followed by a spaced-separated list of all the prime factors.
- This list is piped to `dc` which evaluates the following `e`xpression:

  - `?` reads the whole line as input.  dc cannot parse the input number followed by the colon, so it ignores it.  Then it parses all the space-separated prime factors and pushes them to the stack.
  - `z` takes the number of items on the stack (number of prime factors) and pushes that to the stack
  - `r` reverses the top two items on the stack
  - `^` exponentiates, giving the required answer
  - `p` prints it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxC8IwFAb371e8wVXoy0uaFAenbg7iJogQk0gEMZIKgvS/x3a44Y67@Sm3b348E9Xk445iQQq50OY0Hg9nmunS7j58Sp1joG3a/@r13WJ5pabhoAyUhR7AihcMRAtYhCGrce86C6fErLnnzizXoJ1ly/gD)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 5 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @LuisMendo

```
&YFw^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy3SrTzu/38LAA)

Comment: I think `YfY'w^` should work for 6.

Comment: Or `&YFw^` for 5

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>9</sup> 8 bytes

```
2^~/@p:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY69CsJAEIT7PMViEwMasz/J7gUCgmBlZa@NGMRGn8BXP3MXuYvFcjsfM7P39Ku6HGHooYQNNNBPs63hcD4dPV0/u/27v/iqKO63xwvWI0gFA0iSFqRLktqgmTLQAEhz3gWAZIkgYfQ0smSxiIQTYuGI0HIZMscsqqJkzL94eLO3syZ@Rm2Jjbidm@dt4cemje1iRn8ZdGKKOp92qkydTkn/BQ)

- `2 p: ]` returns a list of primes and their exponents.
- `^~/@` then swap the arguments and exponentiate

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
n=input()
p=2
q=-1
while n%p:p+=1
while n:n/=p;q+=1
print q**p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6vA1oir0FbXkKs8IzMnVSFPtcCqQNsWzrXK07ctsC4EiRQUZeaVKBRqaRX8/29oZmhgaggA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-lm`, 47 bytes

```c
p;f(n){for(p=1;n%++p;);p=pow(log(n)/log(p),p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLtaoMwFP3fp7gUCmojNh9tIln3Z@wp1jI6q05wMVRhsuKrz92ktttgE3JvPOd@nJski8ssG0eri8CE56I5BXZLtVksl1aH2m5t8x7UTYlk4pwNiQ31MFamg7dDZYJwdp4Bfg7o8rZ7Nk972CJwFgQUAbbGJQmIlABQRr1FjAvutpw7BLjH6EatMFQxvnYs3dDVmg4a@SSCrmmgbkwJqBE4i1@qzjclNBVKUukDo@QmJu9t3nf50ctxYlAAZxcxlDllK@Gs68SocqiUVKC/iJHKu6sYoRRzCHb5XwzWSKXkbCMFH3SUgFeTvR5OEZwuQua7/pHt@vQB13pO4Oc/nw965lNc2cBNUZlj3mPeSk/bO2irj7wpgut8YTIB0Q3RsFz66BAul3M9E4OVpkvy/F7/onOkb8f2V0CLAe6dfKP2hHgRzBdHiO8B7aLdGRzLEGgJzowlt9Dup4xhNoyfWVEfynaM67cv)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ḋ⟨l^h⟩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/w93dD@avyInLuPR/JX//0eb6ChY6CgYmQKxuY6CiaWOgqGRIYgAihibGANZxsZAvjFYwNDMwgCoysLI2BQsZWZoYApSbGliYW5obhj7PwoA) On the prime decomposition `ḋ` (like `[5, 5]`), length `l` `^` first element `h`.

A nicer and more Brachylog-y solution, that is one byte longer:

```
 ~^ṗᵐ↔≜^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/3VxD3dOBzIetU151Dkn7v//aBMdBQsdBSNTIDbXUTCx1FEwNDIEEUARYxNjIMvYGMg3BgsYmlkYAFVZGBmbgqXMDA1MQYotTSzMDc0NY/9HAQA) Reverse `~^` to get two Numbers `[A,B]` so that `Input = A^B`, while both are prime `ṗᵐ`. Flip `↔` the list to `[B,A]`, actually find the numbers `≜` and output `B^A`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
k
ÊpUg
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=awrKcFVn&input=MTMzMQ)

```
k\nÊpUg     :Implicit input of integer U
k           :Prime factors
 \n         :Reassign to U
   Ê        :Length
    p       :Raised to the power of
     Ug     :First element of U
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>47 46</s>  44 bytes

Uses a recursive function that first looks for the smallest divisor \$k\ge2\$ of \$n\$ and then counts how many times \$n\$ can be divided by \$k\$. The result is raised to the power of \$k\$.

```javascript
n=>(k=2,g=_=>n%k?n>1&&g(k++):1+g(n/=k))()**k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHLbsIwEEX3fEU2IJsUknmEmVRy@BSEKETUyEGA@vtpUSJknHo3OsfXd@Tv/c/@fridr49V6L6O/cn1wTXGO/xo3c41Ye63oYHFojU@z@0n5K0JhfPWGrtc@v7QhXt3Oa4vXWtOhrPhWJsVRcazd6pvtE4oVjElTLHEGCXBXMcYUBMOCPH1kqdCFQtMCSemmIOmDYAIogYiwKlC4yPjin9TmrHRUl6C6NRQpOrZZDCGaRICZQWvT1DFf3KgZhUQGNvWIoQbYep/AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (          // main function taking n
  k = 2,        // start with k = 2
  g = _ =>      // g is a recursive function ignoring its input
    n % k ?     //   if k is not a divisor of n:
                //     this point of the code is reached during the first step
                //     of the algorithm; but it's also reached on the last
                //     iteration when n = 1, which is why ...
      n > 1 &&  //     ... we test whether n is greater than 1 ...
        g(k++)  //       ... in which case we do a recursive call with k + 1
    :           // else (k has been found):
      1 +       //   add 1 to the final result
      g(n /= k) //   and do a recursive call with n / k
)()             // initial call to g
** k            // raise the result to the power of k
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](http://cran.r-project.org) <s>36</s> <s>28</s> <s>1</s> 36 bytes

Using the fact that exactly `p` powers of `n` are factors of `n^p`:

```r
sum(a<-!max(b<-2:scan())%%b)^b[a][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0VyPRRlcxN7FCI8lG18iqODkxT0NTU1U1STMuKToxNtow9r/FfwA)

but using a function definition does better (by moving `function(m)` to the header part!)

```r
f=function(m)
sum(a<-!m%%(b<-2:m))^b[a][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZptWmpdckpmfp5Gr@b@4NFcj0UZXMVdVVSPJRtfIKldTMy4pOjE22jD2f5pGmoZJnLGmJheIZQ5i/QcA)

with the ultimate improvement in length (1 byte!) produced by defining everything as the function argument (in the header of Try It Online).

```r
f=function(m,b=2:m,a=!m%%b,d=sum(a)^b[a][1]) d
```

but this is not keeping with the code golf spirit!

Comment: It's a beautiful approach, and better than my own best effort, but unfortunately I think you need to include the definition ```function(m)``` or the ```function(m,b=2,...)``` as part of the byte count.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen: this was rather a tongue-in-cheek remark. Using `function` is the code worsens things up: even `pryr::f(sum(a<-!m%%(b<-2:m))^b[a][1])` does not reach 36 bytes...

Comment: by the way, R is the [language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/language-of-the-month-for-september-2020-r), so you might want to add this to the newly-created list of R answers/challenges/tips in September 2020 (see the link).

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>42</s>, 39 bytes

```hs
f x|r<-[2..x]=[z^w|z<-r,w<-r,w^z==x]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBfC4IwFMXf@xQniFCY4f7UJrhe@hhm4INRZBIqOKXvbtcmvtz9zt2557I9ivZVVtXUlW13KdqyhUUWKAYVsg0QGIbEkzgySLGwZhDas0oYuDBecMHpJlarpCGhpFdSSVLcLINcSjJzrblaOvLvn@viOJmYNmmzdoyQxznFn2E@3eG@TRpl4nBwuc3GW/8d06hh/b/cRmtdvt3G07t41vS0T/OsO@woqqgqBNfAMQwhojMoCNZiwH5PPMzsQqzfMv0A)

- 3 bytes saved by @xnor

Comment: You can bind `r` on the outside in a guard as `f x|r<-[2..x]=...`.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
log(n<-scan(),p<-(b=2:n)[!n%%b][1])^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pyc/XSPPRrc4OTFPQ1OnwEZXI8nWyCpPM1oxT1U1KTbaMFYzruC/oZHhfwA)

My best effort, sadly 1-byte longer than the [Xi'an's much-cleverer R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210437/prime-power-switch/210466#210466), but posting anyway in the competitive spirit.

Uses the straightforward approach of finding the prime factor (`p<-(b=2:n)[!n%%b][1]`), then the exponent (`log(n,p)`) and finally raising the exponent to the power of the factor (`log(n,p)^p`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```
n=gets.to_i
p=2
p+=1while n%p>0
w=p**n-1
p (n**n/w%w)**p
```

Port of xnor's Python 3 answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3NDoIwEITv@xR7IdEaleXH9kC9qGcfwfCzUSIpTQEbn76CXCbfTGYybqq@oe4bRo1Fcblfb8HoJ4/DYewfLVidgN1p8q@2YzSRPcfgtRXC7AksbsxMRx/5rRA2LGuAtTq6ibHpAZE/ZYf/B8dDPaeV4/INbJpAaUpAUlImIaUkX4VOKpYg1coU5wSZUsnifw) (headers and footers courtesy of ovs. :D)

Comment: I’m no expert in Ruby, so there might be a better way, but here is a working test setup: https://tio.run/##JY3NDoIwEITv@xR7IdEaleXH9kC9qGcfwfCzUSIpTQEbn76CXCbfTGYybqq@oe4bRo1Fcblfb8HoJ4/DYewfLVidgN1p8q@2YzSRPcfgtRXC7AksbsxMRx/5rRA2LGuAtTq6ibHpAZE/ZYf/B8dDPaeV4/INbJpAaUpAUlImIaUkX4VOKpYg1coU5wSZUsnifw

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ǐ₌Lhe
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLGmyIsIseQ4oKMTGhlIiwiO1rGm2AgPT4gYGo74oGLIiwiWzQsIDgsIDI1LCAyNywgNDksIDEyMSwgMTI1LCAzNDMsIDEzMzEsIDMxMjUsIDE2ODA3LCA4MjM1NDMsIDE2MTA1MSwgMTk0ODcxNzFdIl0=)

### How?

```
ǐ₌Lhe
ǐ     # Prime factors with duplicates
 ₌    # Apply both of next two elements and push both results to the stack:
  L   #  Length
   h  #  First item
    e # Exponentiate these two (length ^ first item)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
#2^#&@@@FactorInteger@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxCsIwEED3/kYg0wm9XNKkg3KT4CY4isIRUu3QCCGb2F@P7fCG93iL1HdapM5R2nRsyjyVZuazxPopl1zTKxVWul3LnOtdHU4Tq4deb1Hy@u0sBDAOjAc7AhrccECWAIkQaDccQu8hGHJ7HrB32zXa4NFj92t/)

Returns `{q^p}`, a singleton list.

```
        FactorInteger@# (* {{p,q}} *)
#2^#&@@@                (* { q^p } *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 59 bytes

```
.+
*
~`(?=(__+?)\1*$)((?=(_+)(\3+)$)\4)+
_+¶$$.($.1*$($#2$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9Pm0uLqy5Bw95WIz5e214zxlBLRVMDzNXW1Igx1tZU0Ywx0dTmitc@tE1FRU9DRQ@oQkNF2UhF6/9/Ey4LLiNTLiNzLhNLLkMjQyA25TI2MeYyNDY25DIG8QzNLAzMAQ) Link includes faster test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
(?=(__+?)\1*$)((?=(_+)(\3+)$)\4)+
```

First, find the smallest nontrivial factor, which will necessarily be `p`. Secondly, count the number of times `q` that `n` can be replaced with its largest proper factor. (The proper factor will be `n/p` on the first pass and eventually decrease to `1` which is left unmatched but this doesn't affect the result.)

```
_+¶$$.($.1*$($#2$*
```

Generate a Retina stage which takes `n` as input and calculates (in decimal) the result of multiplying `1` by `q` `p` times, thus calculating `q^p`.

```
~`
```

Evaluate the resulting code, thus calculating the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```scala
n=>2 to n find(n%_<1)map{p=>import math._;pow(log(n)/log(p),p)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVHbasMwDH33VwjTQQxeVl9aO9sSKOxlD2MfsI3ipm6bkdom8W6Ufntnt5sM1pF1jrCksTW9OfnVu20jPJnOgf2O1q1HWIQAB/RpetjcwqOLUDfwHGLn3cuD/1j19g3qk6sbDtGDg03n1oW7Wt4zsjfhEOqm2wc/RNibuCuXd8F/Fb3fFo7cZBcIDeR4whhLChJpChXiMwqCI64ocIVkRYFxjRhnKZ7KjBKBS4GEFAkwrRATImWZUkwqJM6EfCM219NURukcaC5mWXHxKcems6SSWvNznlVSK6ZyoUopwedKivSxcgx9Fwv86jApc09j3SCA8f@dAia5u3aX5gTJWjNaWAyD@SkcHciZnS3PcLAj1LApXBl9GiYptzZe4B8pDJ2LvStGPHFw3cAkKWhaRkiLset6MmCSmEeUzukX)

Finds the first factor of `n`, which must be `p` because `n` is a prime power, then finds \$\log_p(n)^p\$. Returns an `Option[Double]` that's a `Some[Double]` if the input is valid.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆFẎṪ*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm9vDXX0Pd67SUvl/uP1R05rI//9NdBQsdBSMTIHYXEfBxFJHwdDIEEQARYxNjIEsY2Mg3xgsYGhmYQBUZWFkbAqWMjM0MAUptjSxMDc0NwQA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆFẎ*@Ɲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm9vDXX1aDsfm/j/c/qhpTeT//yY6ChY6CkamQGyuo2BiqaNgaGQIIoAixibGQJaxMZBvDBYwNLMwAKqyMDI2BUuZGRqYghRbmliYG5obAgA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆfL*ḢƊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5qP1sMdi451/T/c/qhpTeT//yY6ChY6CkamQGyuo2BiqaNgaGQIIoAixibGQJaxMZBvDBYwNLMwAKqyMDI2BUuZGRqYghRbmliYG5obAgA)

A 5-byter feels possible...

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
2^~/@p:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jeLq9B0KrGL/K/g56SlwRVsB@UZqBVZcEL5hnL5DjR6SQI2emp4GiK8JFdCo1lNW1lTTK0RREW@oVghUovk/TcHQyJQLSFqaWJgbmhtWAAA)

J has a built-in that gives the prime factorization of a given integer in prime-exponent form. Then it's just a matter of applying exponentiation in reverse (`^~`) between the two numbers.

(Happens to be the same as [Jonah's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210439/91267); somehow didn't notice before I submitted the answer...)

---

Because it is also solvable using `f&.g` ("Under"; do action g, do action f, then undo action g), here are some interesting ones:

#### 10 bytes

```
|.&.(2&p:)
     2&p:  Prime factorization into prime-exponent form
|.         Swap the prime and exponent
  &.       Undo `2&p:`; evaluate the "prime" raised to "exponent"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/a/TU9DSM1AqsNP8r@DnpKXBFW8XV6YMEuCB8wzh9hxo9JAGEDqiARrWesrKmml4hiop4Q7VCoBLN/2kKhkamXEDS0sTC3NDcsAIA)

#### 10 bytes

```
({.##)&.q:
        q:  Prime factorization into plain list of primes
 {.         Head (prime)
   #        Copies of
    #       Length (exponent)
 {.##       Essentially swap the role of prime and exponent
      &.    Undo `q:`; product of all "primes"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Nar1lJU11fQKrf4r@DnpKXBFW8XV6RupFVhxQfiGcfoONXpIAjV6anoaIL4mVABhBLKKeEO1QqASzf9pCoZGplxA0tLEwtzQ3LACAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 13 bytes

```
/ \f~#oE/
 i@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fISatTjnfVZ9LIdPh/38jUzMA)

**Explanation:**

```
/           Switch to Ordinal mode
 i          Push the input as a string
  \         Switch to Cardinal mode
   f        Pop n, implicitly convert n to an integer, 
            and push the prime factors of n as pairs of prime and exponent
    ~       Swap the top two elements of the stack
     #      Skip the next command
       E    Pop y, pop x. If y is non-negative, push x ^ y
        /   Switch to Ordinal mode
      o     Pop s, then output s as a string.
    ~       Swap the top two elements of the stack.
  \         Switch to Cardinal mode
  @         Terminate the program
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 85 bytes

```forth
: f dup 2 do dup i mod 0= if i leave then loop tuck swap s>f fln s>f fln f/ s>f f** ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczNDkQwGIXhvas4awmjMkllhHsR7YcoX0Nx@fUXY/U@Z3OIJ9dGDZ3x/geCWixSKL7QYWCFpEBHh42uVg3X6hGG2cItdY95qyzmkkBm/Jc@N8MQuc@OV4pRT4FIxWspxVc@0@8)

Works like [Noodle9's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210455/78410). Takes an integer and returns a floating-point number on the FP stack.

#### How it works

```forth
: f ( n -- float )
  dup 2 do           \ loop from i = 2..n-1
    dup i mod 0= if  \ if n % i == 0
      i leave        \ ( n p ) we found p; leave the loop
    then             \ end if
  loop               \ end loop
  tuck swap          \ ( p p n )
  s>f fln s>f fln    \ ( p F:ln(n) F:ln(p) )
  f/                 \ ( p F:q ) q = ln(n)/ln(p)
  s>f f**            \ ( F:q**p )
;
```

Comment: <sup>woah..</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>7</s></sup> 6 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

```
^lPQhP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYo7DoAgEAX7dwx6DcvyvYA1XMDKAhMjJtp4eVcoppjJXO9TZSlzkfXIpWYRpWARYRxMgE0gQx0HtgxiJvAw8lEHRMNuZE/a9SvZGCjQ165nb@ct0/YD)

### Explanation

```
^lPQhP
 l      # length of
  PQ    # prime factors of input
^       # raised to power of
    hP  # first element in prime factors of input
```

Comment: I think using `J` wastes a byte here: `^lPQhP`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

<sup>Fixed a bug kindly pointed out by @DominicvanEssen</sup>

```
method(i,p :=2;while(i%p>0,p=p+1);i log(p)floor pow(p))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5BCoMwFET3/xQfoZBQF/5ETazYI/QEbizVGojmoxaPn8aBgXnDLMaFOOGjwz4u4zGHj3A5J1btOTs/CnfjZ5Fzx3eSrUMfvoLl5EPYkMOZsoxZCRZUBcpA2QApSq5AlxpIawJ9EdW2MGCVrq66pqJKq6a0hgxluLN3h8j6NZO4DJwuACZNwuGwv37Le9wk8ubWw68g4x8)

Comment: Do you maybe have your ```i``` and ```p``` the [wrong way around](https://tio.run/##FY5BCoMwFET3/xQfoZBQF/5ETazYI/QEbizVGojmoxaPn8aBgXnDLMaFOOGjwz4u4zGHj3A5J1btOTs/CnfjZ5Fzx3eSrUMfvoLl5EPYkMOZsoxZCRZUBcpA2QApSq5AlxpIawJ9EdW2MGCVrq66pqJKq6a0hgxluLN3h8j6NZO4DJwuACZNwuGwv37Le9wk8ubWw68g4x8)?

Answer (score 1):

**APL (NARS2000 0.5.14), <strike>9 characters</strike> 8 characters (thanks to gurus in APL Orchard):**

```
(⍴*1∘↑)π
```

**How it works:**

Take input 8 as example. `π` breaks down 8 into vector of prime factors `2 2 2`. The [fork](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/Introduction/Trains.htm) `⍴*1∘↑` takes one element from `2 2 2` as exponent, applies this to length of vector `2 2 2` which is `3`, giving `3^2 = 9`.

Comment: (≢*⊃)⍭ In dyalog extended

Comment: I've learned from APL Orchard gurus that the outer ∘ can be saved, which reduces my answer to 8-char. Translating your (≢*⊃)⍭ into NARS2000 would be (≢*↑)π

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 34 bytes

```factor
[ factors dup length swap last ^ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5NDoIwEIX3PcWcgFDKT9EDGDdujCujSVOLEKBgO8QY49lr08Is5s3ke28yjZA4GXc5H0@HHYwC22Q23ahs0gRiwarXorRUFnpltBqiqVm0xG7SFmajED8@pBH2hHwJ@MpD56FnRZQqkjoIzeiqkbKcxZ2xCNhGaMnTGOUZKzZbSdNivVDnvKIVJT/irrB9/VhmGJR@Ygv2LfwsLMIdbm70i0Uh@8T9AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>61</s> 10+38=48 bytes

```
l=log_m(n)
\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}(sign(l-ceil(l))+1)l^m
```

[View it online](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ym7ev8es6e) (note that large values may fail because Desmos doesn't handle large numbers well)

I decided to revisit this because I felt like outgolfing myself, and I remember this having potential inefficiencies. I could only find one improvement, but it seemed substantial enough for the edit.

Input is via the variable `n`, output via the second calculation. If taking input via a variable feels wrong, feel free to add two bytes for a `n=`.

Not horribly efficiently golfed. About 70% of the code is just dedicated to finding one factor, and there's surely a more efficient way to factor numbers in Desmos, but I haven't found one yet, and Desmos is lacking in built-ins relating to factorization or prime numbers.

Instead, we simply observe that since \$p\$ and \$q\$ are prime, then \$p*p...*p\$ must be the only factorization of \$n\$ which can be represented with integer values, because the list of \$p\$s cannot be split into any other even groups. Therefore, we can just interate through all integers \$m \in 2,3,...,n-1\$ and find the value satisfying \$log_mn \in \mathbb{Z}\$ (the set of integers). We do this in the code using  `sign(log_m(n)-ceil(log_m(n)))+1`, which gives us a nice 1 when integeral and 0 when not. We multiply by `log_m(n)^m` to give us our new value, and add up the results for all values 2 through n-1 to single out the answer.

Comment: Can be [37 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bdbk6eamdy) through various golfs. The most significant golf is replacing `sign(l-ceil(l))+1` with `0^{mod(l,1)}`, which also gives 1 when `l` is an integer, and 0 if not.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
§^←Lp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DyuEdtE3wK/v//b2hsbAgA)